# How to get SQL code to show any negative value as 0? Orderwise query builder

Tags: sql

Unsure if anyone will be able to assist due to unique software but....

We use a stock management system which has a SQL query builder for custom stock reports and the code below looks at various fields in our system and shows a figure which represents a stock quantity.

We would like to have the report only show figure of 0 and above so need he code to say:

IF less than 0, then just show as 0.

EDIT: I did not build the code, just wanted to see if it can be amended.

```
CASE
  WHEN [Variant Setting].Manufactured = 0 THEN (SELECT CASE
                                                         WHEN [Variant Stock Location].[Free stock quantity] < 0 THEN 0
                                                         ELSE [Variant Stock Location].[Free stock quantity]
                                                       END
                                                FROM   [Variant Stock Location]
                                                WHERE  [Variant Stock Location].[Product ID] = [Variant Detail].[Product ID]
                                                       AND [Variant Stock Location].[Stock location] = 2)
  ELSE ((SELECT Round(Min(x.atb), 0, 1)
         FROM   (SELECT IsNull((SELECT Sum([Variant Transaction Header Total].[Free stock])
                                FROM   [Variant Transaction Header Total]
                                       JOIN [Variant Transaction Header]
                                         ON [Variant Transaction Header].[Transaction ID] = [Variant Transaction Header Total].[Header ID]
                                       JOIN [Bin Number]
                                         ON [Bin Number].[Bin number ID] = [Variant Transaction Header].[Bin number]
                                WHERE  [Variant Transaction Header].Product = [Product Revision Component].[Component Product]
                                       AND [Variant Transaction Header].[Stock location] = 2
                                       AND ( [Bin Number].[Bin type] = 1
                                              OR ( [Bin Number].[Bin type] = 2
                                                   AND [Bin Number].[Fallover picking bin] = 1
                                                   AND (SELECT system_setting.ss_allow_replenishment_fallover_picking_bin
                                                        FROM   system_setting) = 1 ) )
                                       AND [Variant Transaction Header].[Transaction type] <> 7
                                       AND [Variant Transaction Header].[Transaction type] <> 12
                                       AND [Variant Transaction Header].[Transaction type] <> 18
                                       AND [Variant Transaction Header].[Transaction type] <> 23), 0.00) / [Product Revision Component].Quantity AS atb
                 FROM   [Product Revision]
                        JOIN [Product Revision Component]
                          ON [Product Revision Component].[BOM ID] = [Product Revision].ID
                        JOIN [Variant Detail] variant_detail2
                          ON variant_detail2.[Product ID] = [Product Revision Component].[Component Product]
                 WHERE  [Product Revision].[BOM Product] = [Variant Detail].[Product ID]
                        AND ( [Product Revision].[Order line ID] = 0
                               OR [Product Revision].[Order line ID] IS NULL )
                        AND ( [Product Revision].[Purchase order line ID] = 0
                               OR [Product Revision].[Purchase order line ID] IS NULL )
                        AND ( [Product Revision].[Customer return line ID] = 0
                               OR [Product Revision].[Customer return line ID] IS NULL )) x))
END )
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, that is a ridiculous expression.  What is not working in it?

Comment: Sorry, but who's your teacher?!? Why He does NOT teaching you to use `join`'s?

Comment: Please change this question to an [mre]...

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition in your `CASE WHEN` :

```
    CASE
      WHEN yourcalculatedColumn < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE yourcalculatedColumn
```